# Skype 4.3 IM does not display attached photos

Tags: skype

Skype 4.3 IM does not display attached photos.

It only shows a weblink. There is also a download window that pops up when Skype is started and nothing seems to download. I think these are some of the pictures.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

*A note from the future:* Since Microsoft retired the *Skype* application (v4.*) and replaced it with *Skype for Linux* (v7+) media are embedded directly into the conversation screen.

---

This appears to be by design:

> If you don't see a picture you were sent, but instead see a link, don't worry; this is only temporary.
>
> [image]
>
> As part of Skype's move to a cloud-based architecture, pictures sent via chat are now uploaded to the cloud. All of our Skype clients are currently moving to this new cloud-based architecture, and once we complete the rollout, your pictures will show (as normal) inside the conversation. For the moment, to view the picture that your contact sent, all you have to do is click the link and log in.
>
> […]
>
> *Skype 5.0 for iOS (and above), Skype 5.1 for Android (and above), Skype 1.8 on Xbox One, Skype 6.20 for Windows desktop, Skype 7.0 for Mac, and Skype 2.21 for Windows Phone (and above) users might also see pictures appear in their chats as pictures.* [Learn more](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA34491/). [emphasis added]

([Source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34458/why-don-t-i-see-the-picture-my-contact-sent-me) – I had to disable the “Cloud-to-Butt” browser add-on for this one)

It's noteworthy, that Skype for Linux *does not appear* in the list of supported platforms for the soon-to-return feature, to have images embedded in the chat window again. The *[Learn more](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA34491/)* link repeats the emphasised portion and platforms.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!